# Add article sharing button - wordpress post grid

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, elementor, article, blog-post

I would like to have a blog post grid with social buttons (the “share this entry” functionality) in each element of the grid (every element of the grid would be: thumbnail, then below, title, and then below, the social buttons).(See attached image)
The user would have to be able to share the post as a thumbnail without having to click on the post.
Is it possible with wordpres, my builder is elementor and the template JupiterX?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpcHM.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the share buttons inside the loop template directly

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how do you do that ?

Comment: It seems you are not a programmer , so i would recommend this
[plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-to-any/)
easy to use and no need to put any code in your theme